# Adapter for retina macbook pro to external monitor

Tags: display, macbook-pro

What adapter will provide the best resolution/image quality for extending my late 2013 macbook pro retina display to a 24" AOC 2436VH monitor? The monitor has HDMI and VGA (d sub). Do I want mini display port to HDMI, or just an HDMI cable or VGA? I will mainly use it for working/writing, not for movies or anything (if it matters).

Comment: It's not going to make any difference what kind of cable you use.

Comment: roger that. five more words to go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacBook Pro retina display already comes with a HDMI. so all you have to do is buy a quality HDMI cable and connect them together. Then MacOSX will recognise the display and then you can use it as a normal display.